# Equivalent of Splunk's lookup in Kusto Query Language

Tags: azure, splunk, splunk-query, kql

I am trying to find the equivalent of Splunk Query Language's **lookup** command in Kusto Query Language.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 2 languages are not equal, so you won't always find an equivalent for each operator in one language in the other language.

that said, have a look at the docs for the Kusto [lookup operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/lookupoperator)

Comment: I went through (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/lookupoperator), but this is not what exactly I was looking for but it did give me a workaround scenario. I Will explore more. Thanks so much, @Yoni Leibowitz